# OOP and switch statements

Tags: php, oop, software-design

I have this OOP code in php

```
class SSE {

static function setSection($opt_name,array $settings){
    var_dump($settings["fields"]);

    foreach ($settings["fields"] as $field){
        self::processField($opt_name,$field);
    }

}

static function processField($opt_name,array $field){

        switch ($field["type"]){
            case "number":
                $number = new Number($field["title"],$field["desc"],$field["id"]);
                echo "<br>$number";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                $checkbox = new Checkbox($field["title"],$field["desc"],$field["id"],$field["color"]);
                echo "<br>$checkbox";
                break;
        }
}

}

class Input {

protected $title;
protected $desc;
protected $id;

}

class Number extends Input {

//protected $fields = array();

function __toString(){
    return $this->title;
}

public function __construct($title,$desc,$id){
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->desc = $desc;
    $this->id = $id;
}
}

class Checkbox extends Input {

//protected $fields = array();
protected $color;
function __toString(){
    return $this->title;
}

public function __construct($title,$desc,$id,$color){
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->desc = $desc;
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->color = $color;
}
}

$test1 = array(
"title" => "Ssadassa",
"id" => "basic",
"desc" =>"this is a test",
"fields" => array(
    array(
        "title" => "Checkbox input",
        "id" => "ba32132sic",
        "desc" =>"this is a test",
        "type"  => "checkbox",
        "color" => "This is only for checkbox no another input should have this"
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Number input",
        "id" => "basic",
        "desc" =>"this is a test",
        "type"  => "number"
    )
)

);

SSE::setSection("da",$test1);
```

What to do about the switch statement?Later I may add textarea input and I have to go and edit the switch statemt.I have looked here https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns but I don't know with one fits this case maybe factory no idea.This is my first OOP try.
By the way the array $test1 must not be changed I mean the way some one uses those clases must be the same.Any help really appreciated.Thank you.
Edit:The question is:Is anything wrong if I use the switch statement?Is a better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, what?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately you seem to have placed yourself in the corner with that design. The problem is each subclass implements a different constructor signature so you can't generalize them. I think the switch is your best option. When you do add a textbox you can just add another case.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, if all subclasses implemented the same constructor signature you could have done: `$classname = ucfirst($field["type"]); $field = new $classname($arg1,$arg2,$arg3)`

Comment: And what will be a better design from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create class map, and special methods to create inputs from options.

```
class SSE { // please rename this

    static private $mapClass = ['number' => 'Number', 'checkbox' => 'Checkbox'];

    static function setSection($opt_name, array $settings) {
        // var_dump($settings["fields"]);

        foreach ($settings["fields"] as $field) {
            self::processField($opt_name, $field);
        }
    }

    static function processField($opt_name, array $field) {
        // recognize class from class map
        $class = self::$mapClass[$field["type"]];
        $input = $class::createFromOptions($field);
        echo "<br>$input";
    }

}

class Input {

    protected $title;
    protected $desc;
    protected $id;

}

class Number extends Input {

//protected $fields = array();

    function __toString() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function __construct($title, $desc, $id) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->desc = $desc;
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    // create object from array
    static public function createFromOptions(array $options) {
        return new self($options["title"], $options["desc"], $options["id"]);
    }

}

class Checkbox extends Input {

//protected $fields = array();
    protected $color;

    function __toString() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function __construct($title, $desc, $id, $color) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->desc = $desc;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    // create object from array
    static public function createFromOptions(array $options) {
        return new self($options["title"], $options["desc"], $options["id"], $options["color"]);
    }

}

$test1 = array(
    "title" => "Ssadassa",
    "id" => "basic",
    "desc" => "this is a test",
    "fields" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "Checkbox input",
            "id" => "ba32132sic",
            "desc" => "this is a test",
            "type" => "checkbox",
            "color" => "This is only for checkbox no another input should have this"
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "Number input",
            "id" => "basic",
            "desc" => "this is a test",
            "type" => "number"
        )
    )
);

SSE::setSection("da", $test1);
```

Also, you could add options validator to make sure that all mandatory options has passed and there is no extra options.

Why not `ucfirst`? Because you are able to use camel case class name, for example RichText (textarea with wysiwyg). Or write more smart class recognizer.